# How can I use relative path to read local files in Django app?

Tags: python, django, relative-path

My django app has to read some text files from the file system. So I make a directory in my app directery, and use relative path to open and read from the file.

```
areas = parseXmlFile('xml_files/area.xml')
```

When I run server to debug using `manage.py runserver`, that's ok. But I run server using       `manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8081` , Django can't find the file: `No such file or directory: 'xml_files/area.xml'`

I don't want to use absolute path, that means I need to modify much code.

How can I solve the problem to use relative path to open local file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use `absolute path` but in a more clever way. Declare in your `settings.py` something like `XMLFILES_FOLDER` and have your `settings.py` like this:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))
XMLFILES_FOLDER = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'xml_files/')
```

This is assuming that `xml_files` folder lives under the project root folder, if not, just declare the relative path from the project root folder to the `xml_files`

```
XMLFILES_FOLDER = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'f1/f2/xml_files/')
```

That way, wherever in your code you want to access a file inside that directory you just do:

```
from settings import XMLFILES_FOLDER
path = XMLFILES_FOLDER+'area.xml'
```

This approach will work in any OS, and no matter you change the folder of the project, it will still work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 35):

@Paulo Bu's answer is correct, but outdated. Modern-day settings.py files have a BASE_DIR variable you can use for this endeavour.

```
import os
from yourproject.settings import BASE_DIR
file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'relative_path')
```

Bear in mind that the relative path is from your Django project's root folder.

Comment: It's better to use `from django.conf import settings`, it's more structure-independent.